# Send event from ec2 machine to the office

Tags: ruby, events, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

i am implementing a system which uses amazon ec2.
I need a mechanism which allows a callbacl from ec2 machine to my office.
ec2 machines have no connectivity to my office so i need to find an alternative way.
In the office i have a grape API and, and the callback should use that grape API.
I thought about using SQS in the ec2 machine and to put a little agent in the office that will listen on a certain queue and than it will forward the requests to the API, but it sounds too sloppy.
Is there a better way of doing it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your grape api publicly available?

Comment: Nope, only in my office :)

Answer (score 0):

What about establishing a VPN connection between your office and EC2?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario4.html